# Map configuration in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

We have an requirement in Hibernate, that is suppose, we have a class name Employee , which contains list of Departments. But here Department doesn't contain any fields , which contain only one map that is contains department fields. So please tell me the Hibernate configuration of Employee and Department classes.

Thanks,
Narsi p

Comment: In Employee Class, i mapped like  @ElementCollection
    private List<Department> deptList;

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some example code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are talking about unidirectional one-to-many relation?
In this case you should use

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Department> departments;

    public Set<Department> getDepartments() {
        return departments;
    }

    public void setDepartments(Set<Department> departments)
    {
        this.departments = departments;
    }
    //....
```

}

```java
@Entity
public class Department {
    // No link to Employee
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
    //....
```

}

In this scenario you hav a reference from **Employee** to **Department**, but no reference from **Department** to **Employee**.

**UPD1:**

In case you want to map basic types, you can use *@ElementCollection* as was mentioned by narsi:

```java
@ElementCollection
Map<String, String> departments;
```

Comment: Yes Amuza, Same like this only, But in Department , we don't have id and name properties, We have only Map<String,String>. So How do we configure Department in this scenario.